# Configure DocuSign to send a visualforce page(rendered as PDF)

Tags: apex, visualforce, docusign

I need to send an email with a PDF attachment that needs a signature from the recipient with salesforce. DocuSign seems to be the app to use. How do I configure DocuSign app to send my visualforce page as the attachment and not open the page to create a new envelope?

I have already gone through  http://developer.force.com/cookbook/recipe/accessing-docusign-api-from-salesforcecom-to-send-contracts-for-esignatures 
but the problem with that way is that it doesn't create dsfs__DocuSign_Status__c records to track the status of the document.

I have also thought about a custom button, (https://www.docusign.com/sites/default/files/DocuSign%20for%20Salesforce%20Custom%20Button%20Logic.pdf) but cannot find how to create an attachement from a VF page.

Comment: Refer http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/57810/attaching-a-visualforce-page-rendered-as-pdf-to-docusign-email for the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can use DocuSiggn soap API to create the email attachment and to track it, can use the docusign app.Refer [Attaching a visualforce page rendered as PDF to Docusign email](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/57810/attaching-a-visualforce-page-rendered-as-pdf-to-docusign-email) for the complete answer explained.